# Add a function to String class using JavaScript's String.prototype

Tags: javascript, string, prototype

I have to create a function to be added to the string class. For example "hi".exclamify(3) should return hi with three !!! at the end of the string. I know I have to make use of

```
String.prototype.exclamify = function(n) 
{
  // Function definition goes here
  console.log(this);
}
"hi".exclamify(2);
```

When I call the function as "hi".exclamify(2); the console returns [String: 'Hello'], what to do to get only the value of the string which is "Hello"? I used Object.values(this) which returned [ 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' ]. I want the exact string to implement the function.

Comment: Please note the function here

String.Prototype.exclamify=function(n){

console.log(this)
}

Comment: The "P" in "prototype" should be lowercase.

Comment: Please fix formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the value of `this` was working for you and contained the correct string. Here's a quick try at your problem:

```js
String.prototype.exclamify=function(n){ return `${this}${'!'.repeat(n)}` }

const testString = "hello";

console.log(testString.exclamify(3));
console.log(testString.exclamify(5));
```